# angularjs how to avoid dynamic html compilation in controller?

Tags: google-maps, angularjs

I am using google maps api to display some infowindow (google maps balloon windows).

```
var contentString = '<div id="content"><p>hello world</p></div>';
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});
//... add info window to google map object
```

This will display 'Hello world' in a balloon, when you click on a map marker. (A map marker is an icon on the map like the red pins you are used to.

I wanted the content of the infoWindow to be dynamic so I set the *contentString* to:

`"<div id='infoWindowContent' ngInclude='/Content/Static/MapPersonDetails.html'></div>";`

This gets inserted into the DOM of the page when the user clicks on a map marker.
To make this work I have to compile the above line, when it gets inserted into the DOM of the page.

I am using a directive that abstracts the use of the map like:

```
    <div class="google-map" 
         markers="markersProperty"
         on-Info-Window-Dom-Ready="onInfoWindowDomReady()">
    </div>
```

So, when clicking on a map marker, the directive will create the infoWindow, subscribe to the *domReadyEvent* of the inforWindow, show the infoWindow, and bubble up the *domReadyEvent* to the page controller.

infoWindow exposes a *domReady* event which I bubbled up through the directive, and I do something like this in my page controller:

```
        $scope.onInfoWindowDomReady = function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            var element = document.getElementById("infoWindowContent");
            $compile(element)($scope);
        });
    };
```

**The problem I'm having is that I don't like the dom manipulation I'm doing in the controller. Is there any other way I could do this? Should I put the compile inside the directive?** Then the directive would know that the infoWindow content is dynamic and has to be compiled, which isn't true for all info windows.

An important thing to know is that infoWindow content can also be an html element (as opposed to static string), but I don't know if this can help in any way.

Comment: Did you ever found a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Using angular-ui it becomes a simple as this:

```
<div ng-controller="MapCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="marker in myMarkers" ui-map-marker="myMarkers[$index]"
        ui-event="{'map-click': 'ClickOnMarker(marker)'}">
    </div>

    <div ui-map-info-window="myInfoWindow">
        <input type="text" ng-model="myText" required />
    </div>

    <div id="map_canvas" ui-map="myMap" class="map"
        ui-event="{'map-click': 'ClickMap($event)' }"
        ui-options="mapOptions">
    </div>
</div>

$scope.ClickOnMarker = function (marker) {
    $scope.myText = "Clicked on marker";
    $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.myMap, marker);    
};

$scope.ClickMap = function ($event) {
    var newMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: $scope.myMap,
        position: $event.latLng,
        hasChanges: true,
        isSaved: false,
    });

    $scope.myMarkers.push(newMarker);
    $scope.myText = "Clicked on map";
    $scope.ClickOnMarker($scope.currentMarker);
};
```

Hope it helps!